# File upload in https. Trying to understand the concept how it works

Tags: file, security, ssl

I would like to understand more about file upload. I would like to understand more in perspective of how it works in theory and not at code level.

For instance, the website is in https.
1: I upload a file using this https website.
2: The successful upload file will be convert into bits and bytes and send to the server wrapped in ssl
3: Am I correct to understand that these bits and bytes will be encrypt and prevent man in middle attacks?

Thanks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) When you upload the file, that file is going to split, (1 IP Datagram ~1500 bytes).

2) each part is encapsulated in SSL (now the information is encrypted).

3) Your PC sends all SSL datagrams one by one

4) The server receives all SSL datagrams and then it extracts the information (decrypt).

5) The server joins all parts in one file

6) The server has the original file

I hope that this can help you

Comment: Thanks for the answers